# CDO mail - adding a dynamic list to myMail.HTMLBody

Tags: asp-classic

I have a CDO mail notification that I wish to list various records in the HTMLBody so the recipient can see what's been updated in my db.  I can produce the list and display it if I use Response.Write so I know my record set contains more than a single record -  but when I add this to HTMLBody it will only display the last record and not the list.

Any ideas why this isn't working and only putting a single record into HTMLBody?

```
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "XXXXXXXXXX"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 0
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = ""
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = ""
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Subject= "Test 4" 
myMail.To= mailto
myMail.From="XXXXXXXXX"
myMail.HTMLBody="Date Insert From Super Calendar<br/>"
    if Not rsSQL_cal_adIdlist.EOF then
        Do While Not rsSQL_cal_adIdlist.EOF
            myMail.HTMLBody = "Id Number:"&rsSQL_cal_adIdlist.Fields("adId")&"<br />"
        rsSQL_cal_adIdlist.MoveNext
    Loop
    end if

myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It changes the value of mymail.htmlbody several times before it sends, it doesn't add to it.

You need to create a variable, and concatenate your DB rows to it, something like

```
Dim mymessage

mymessage = "Date Insert From Super Calendar<br/>"
if Not rsSQL_cal_adIdlist.EOF then
    Do While Not rsSQL_cal_adIdlist.EOF
        mymessage = mymessage & "Id Number:"&rsSQL_cal_adIdlist.Fields("adId")&"<br />"
    rsSQL_cal_adIdlist.MoveNext
Loop
end if
```

Then you can create your CDO.Message object later on in the script and use

```
myMail.HTMLBody = mymessage
```